# Force users to add Organic Groups content only to their group(s)

Tags: 7, organic-groups

When a group member try to add group content, how come this user can still choose to witch group this content belongs to?? I was expecting that group members adding content could only add content for their specific group, not for all groups... 
In the event a member is part of several groups then there should be a way to detect from witch group the edit content as been trigger and then only modify the content for that specific group ..

Anyone have such experience to share ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At admin/og/og (D6) you can uncheck the setting "Audience checkboxes". From the description "Show each group that the user is a member of as a checkbox in the "Audience" section. This enables the member to place her post into multiple groups. If unchecked, simplify the user interface by omitting the checkboxes and assuming user wants to post into the current group. This simplification only applies to new nodes, and not to edits of existing nodes. Group administrators always see checkboxes."

Comment: Thanks Nigel, although in drupal 7 this setting is in : 
admin/config/group/fields

Comment: sorry, ur post did not specify. try using the 6 or 7 tag. it may help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to force the target audience on a create/edit form:

1. Make sure that you've added the Groups Audience field to your bundle
   (e.g. content type) through the Organic Groups configuration
   (Adminstration -> Configuration -> Organic Groups -> OG Field
   Settings).
2. In the Administration section, surf to your bundle's (e.g. content type's) "Manage fields" tab.
3. Edit the "Groups audience" field.
4. Check "Required field".
5. If you only want the entity instance (e.g. node) to be placed in N group(s), select N as the "Number of values" field.  By default, it's set to "Unlimited" which you may not want.